# Netmiko "Timed-out reading channel, data not available." for Juniper

Tags: python, automation, netmiko, juniper

I am using netmiko ConnectionHandler to push simple config to a Juniper device. But not sure why its throwing "Timed-out reading channel, data not available." this error. Here is the exact command im using, can someone please help me understand what am i doing wrong?

```
        device = ConnectHandler(device_type="juniper",
                                host="ip_of_device",
                                username=username,
                                password=passwd,
                                session_timeout=120,
                                verbose=True)
        cmdlist = ['routing-instances {', ' SERVICES {', '  instance-type vrf;', '  no-vrf-advertise;', '  vrf-table-label;', ' }', '}', '']
        device.send_config_set(cmdlist, exit_config_mode=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with the similar error. When I have checked the configuration of the device through CLI, I have seen that the configuration I sent via Netmiko was already configured in network device.
So that, I chose to avoid this error using try-except method and mark the devices into a box where the issue is seen. If it is the case, you can also proceed it accordingly. See a sample config:

```
from netmiko.ssh_exception import  NetMikoTimeoutException

for ip in ip_list:
    <snipped>
    try:
        net_connect.send_config_set(cmdlist)  
    except (NetMikoTimeoutException):
        print("The device is faulty:" + ip)
        continue
```